# JS - How to change dynamically an image in my tinymce

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I try to edit my images in the tinymce editor,
I already have an image into it, i try to edit the path of this image to change it dinamically with :

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode().src = '/my/path/'
```

and it works, the image is edited but when i get the html content of my editor, the src still is the old image.

is there an other way to change the source of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's an easy way to do this, here take a look :

Create your custom file browser using `file_browser_callback` : `myFileBrowser,` in your tinymce.init.

Then in your callback function

```
function myFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
  tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open(
    {
      file: './test.html',
      title: 'My File Browser',
      width: 420, // Your dimensions may differ - toy around with them!
      height: 400,
      resizable: 'yes',
      close_previous: 'no',
    },
    {
      window: win,
      input: field_name,
    },
  );
  return false;
}
```

by doing this you tell tiny mce to open a new popup wich is the file 'test.html', and you send to your popup two parameters 
`window : win, input : field_name`.

Then in your test.html you can get those parameters like this :

```
var args = top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams();
```

this will give you an object with your parameters and value. you can now use a little jquery or whatever you want to replace the field of your image value with the path of your new image. and then close your popup.

Hope i helped you.